# How to connect mongodb atlas with java MongoClient?

Tags: java, mongodb

> Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches
>   ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=nearest}. Client view of
>   cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=:27017,
>   type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
>   exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached
>   end of stream}}, {address=:27017, type=UNKNOWN,
>   state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException:
>   Prematurely reached end of stream}}

I'm getting this error while trying to connect MongoDB atlas with Java MongoClient

```java
ServerAddress primaryServer = new ServerAddress(<primary_host>,
                Integer.parseInt(27017));

ServerAddress secondaryServer = new ServerAddress(<secondary_host>,
                Integer.parseInt(27017));

MongoCredential mongoCred = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(<user_name>, <db_name>, <password>.toCharArray());

MongoClientOptions.Builder mongoConf = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
mongoConf.readPreference(ReadPreference.nearest());

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(primaryServer, secondaryServer), Arrays.asList(mongoCred, mongoCred), mongoConf.build());
```

Comment: Have you tried with the [`MongoClientURI`](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#driver-examples) ?

Comment: I tried with MongoClientURI and it is working. So I can't do like above then? i don't want to use uri string. @MasterPro